# Xcode 7 Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: ios, xcode

i updated xcode 7 and gives this error

Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

```
 _recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"], name, extension]] settings:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Show the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: no error just warning like this:  Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Comment: OK start by breaking that statement up into separate statements.  That way you can examine which is `nil` in the debugger and actually understand what it does.  You are making a rod for your own back with such long compound statements.

Answer (score 42):

If what bothers you is the warnings, you can supress that using this **`-Wnonnull`**

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnonnull"

_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"], name, extension]] settings:nil error:nil];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to check is to use `Show Completions` - go to a method name and press <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> or in the menu `Editor` > `Show Completions`. A window will pop up. Look for entries with `(nonnull)` - these must not be `nil`. For example:

[image: (nonnull) sample popup]

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> with the cursor in `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`. As you can see a lot of arguments are marked `(nonnull)`.

When you explicitly pass `nil` in your method call, you already found the problem. If you pass a variable, check whether that is `nil` at that time.

Comment: 'Esc' does the job for me instead of Ctrl-Space (easier to hit)

Comment: @Mindaugas Ah yes - I remember, that the 'esc'-popup annoyed me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while using a custom completion handler . The warning occured while passing nil value for the handler. So I have added `__nullable` with completion.

```
typedef void (^ __nullable completionHandler)(void);
```