# xcode 7 warning: Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

After updating to xcode 7 a warning

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

started appearing at place

```
[self application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:nil];
```

this method is called manually in method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I know this warning is appearing because now `annotation` parameter cannot be `nil` now from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677389/xcode-7-null-passed-to-a-callee-that-requires-a-non-null-argument) but I don't have any idea what to pass there as data type is `id` or there is any other way that I can removing this warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677389/xcode-7-null-passed-to-a-callee-that-requires-a-non-null-argument)

Comment: I checked that answer and I understand that due to passing nil for parameter annotations this warning is coming but I don't what to pass there because the data type is id

Comment: Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44) . If you are not sure what to pass, then simply suppress the warning.

Comment: What does the type have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you don't actually need the `annotations`:

1. Extract the body of your `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` to a new method.
2. Implement `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` by calling the new method.
3. In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` also call the new method.